# Errors in installing Tor on Kali 2016.2 VM

Tags: terminal, software-installation, kali-linux, tor

I am trying to install TOR on Kali Linux 2016.2 but I am getting the following error message.

```
    apt-get install tor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libssl1.0.0 tor-geoipdb torsocks
Suggested packages:
  mixmaster xul-ext-torbutton tor-arm polipo | privoxy apparmor-utils obfsproxy
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl1.0.0 tor tor-geoipdb torsocks
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,034 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali sana/main amd64 libssl1.0.0 amd64 1.0.1k-3
  404  Not Found
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali sana/main amd64 tor amd64 0.2.5.12-1
  404  Not Found
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali sana/main amd64 torsocks amd64 2.0.0-3
  404  Not Found
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali sana/main amd64 tor-geoipdb all 0.2.5.12-1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1k-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/t/tor/tor_0.2.5.12-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/t/torsocks/torsocks_2.0.0-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/t/tor/tor-geoipdb_0.2.5.12-1_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: have you done `apt-get update` first?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes, I did try the above command but still getting the same errors as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free

deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free

deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Overwriting my /etc/apt/sources.list file with the lines above and then using `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get upgrade` solved the problem.

Initially my /etc/apt/sources.list file contained these two lines

`deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free`

I got the solution from one of the answers in this forum

https://forums.kali.org/archive/index.php/t-142.html

Answer (score 0):

Your /etc/apt/sources.list should contain:
    deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

Comment: It does contain the above mentioned statement.